# Cannot #include <fmt> from vcpkg installation

Tags: c++, cmake, build, vcpkg

### Host Environment

- OS: [Windows 11 using WSL (Ubuntu-22.04)]
- Compiler: Clang 14.0.0

### The issue

Firstly, I did `vcpkg install fmt --triplet x64-Linux` and everything worked properly. After that, I wrote some configurations in the top-level CMakeLists.txt to find the FMT package. Then, I linked FMT to my executable, and it was built successfully. However, when I include fmt, an error immediately occured.

**Top-level CMakeLists.txt**
[image: 1]

**CMakeLists.txt in the `app` subdirectory**
[image: 2]

**Main.cpp, the executable that will be generated from; it also shows the error of including FMT**
[image: 3]

**Even the IDE managed to suggest FMT, meaning that it knows it exists**
[image: 4]

**Further evidence of the package already installed**
[image: 5]

### The zip file if you want to inspect

[hp_bot.zip](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/files/10611495/hp_bot.zip)

I tried to modify my include directories in the c_cpp_properties.json but found no luck.

Comment: Stack Overflow discourages **images** which represent textual information. Instead, paste into the question post the code and error message as **text** with proper formatting. See [ask] and that question on meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your vcpkg installation or CMake file. You are just including the wrong headers.

Instead of

```
#include <fmt>
```

(which is a directory)
you should include some of the files within that directory:

```
#include <fmt/core.h>
```